# send string from usercontrol to appliucation page

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-controls, windows-phone

I need to send a string(TextBlockName.Text) from usercontrol to application page after clicking on the button.

Application page XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstFlags">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:ListItem />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

UserControl "ListItem" с# code:

```
public partial class ListItem : UserControl
{
    ...
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

User control Xaml:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click">
    <TextBlock Name="TextBlockName" Text="{Binding ShortName}" />
</Button>
```

So. I think it is necessary to generate event in application page when button clicked. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question !!!!

Comment: UTFG: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/katriend/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-and-the-html-page-let-your-silverlight-do-the-work.aspx?Redirected=true

Comment: It is windows phone application

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to ask here is how you can send the `textblock1.Text` (for example) value to the code behind.

By the looks of it, you're using Data Binding to bind the data, but you also have a `Button_Click` event.

Generally I use one or the other (unless i'm doing something complex), if you simply want to get the `Text` value form the `TextBlock`, then you can either do:

`<TextBlock Name="textBlockName" Text="{Binding ShortName}" Mode="TwoWay">`

The `Mode="TwoWay" ensures that the value of the Text Block gets sent to and from the code-behind object, in this case called`ShortName`and to the`TextBlock.Text`.

The other method is to simply create a Button click event which you already seem to have. In the Button Click event, simply do the following:

`string myString = textBlock1.Text;`

As you can guess, that simply gets the string value that's within the `Text` property of the `textBlock` and puts it inside the `myString` object.

**But** - as an important note, you should try to elaborate as much as possible to ensure that people who are viewing your question understand and can help you.